# Facebook API Insights Issue

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing web application that collects views data about Facebook Posts in video. The problem is that when I try to fetch views data, for example, `57460905720_10156493579175721/insights/post_video_complete_views_organic`,
I get an empty `data` array.

When I append `fields` parameter, like `?fields=description`, I get empty array too.

How to get information about video views?